# React + Redux + Electron desktop application, how to save data on local files

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, nedb

As the title says I want my react-redux application running with node-electron to save some data when few actions fires.

Try 1:

So I tried nedb first but it does not actually create any local database file but only does save data in memory and I lose the data when I close the electron window or restart it. I initialize nedb datastore in redux actions file so I think that it may be called in a sub-process of main electron app or something but I don't know how to work around this problem.

Try 2:

After I tried simple json file module with same setup, when a file save action is fired it tries to save payload to a json file with jsonfile.writeFile method but it also fails here with error that "writeFile" is not a method. It is working perfectly with my node-express app but fails with react-electron setup.

Try 3:

I tried redux-persist and nedb-persist libraries but i think they also save data in local storage and not actually to a file system, so they lose data after a restart...

Any solution to above 2 problems or a new way to save data on local json file or any other offline database solution like nedb will work for me.

Comment: I use redux-persist and the data stays after restart. Did you configure it to auto-rehydrate?

Comment: @Aaron i did called auto-rehtdrate at store create method as shown on its github page. But my data only persist like a session data would. Can you give a code example or something using rehydrate with a particular reducer (only persist data of that reducer) ? Where does redux-persist save data when we restart, does it create any files or something?

Comment: I used only the 3 "basic usage" lines under redux-persist github's page. I did not try the per-reducer logic. My use case is exactly the same as yours (React + Redux + Electron) so I assume you may simply have some config issue.